# Regex negative lookahead for url parameter

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm using this regex to match YouTube playlist URLs and extract the playlist ID:

https://regex101.com/r/pO4dS6/31

However, I don't want the regex to match if one of the parameters is "v=" which designates a single video in the playlist.

In my example above, the first 2 URLs should match and the last 3 should not.

I'm trying to use negative lookahead (?!v=) but it's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Please add all relevant code to the actual question, and only use external links as extra references. If the external link changes or gets removed, this question will be useless for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only testing for an immediate occurrence of `v=`. Allow some other characters to optionally precede it with `.*`:

```
(?!.*v=)
```

See updated on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pO4dS6/32)

It would probably be even more safe to check for the character that must precede the `v=` as well:

```
(?!.*[?&]v=)
```

See updated on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pO4dS6/33)

Comment: Yes! Thanks for explaining it. I didn't know I needed the wildcard - I had thought the lookahead included that by default.

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to manipulate url data, is generally best practice to use url parsing techniques.  This makes `parse_url()` a intuitive candidate.

You didn't show your coding attempt (and you still should), but if you can consider a non-regex solution this will be reliable: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04ecc1a70e0c1d1924b9686ad37b02697c2b2e80))

```
$in=['https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFgquLnL59akaNTxtgsoKn4c0Q8utjqku',
'http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLdwCuEoZ_6l6C47ciTvf6Z2GArUOCHHQ3',
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTMcqVFk39s&index=2&list=PLxgKRG5rfVFa067PHSpju_XaTPiyii31L',
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpbTkbv4L2Y&list=PLvqxe4XbcSiEzrZm28NjsLXmHkffCJmBY&index=2',
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?index=2&list=PLxgKRG5rfVFa067PHSpju_XaTPiyii31L&v=VTMcqVFk39s'];
foreach($in as $v){
    parse_str(parse_url($v)['query'],$array);
    echo (!isset($array['v'])?$array['list']:'disqualified'),"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
PLFgquLnL59akaNTxtgsoKn4c0Q8utjqku
PLdwCuEoZ_6l6C47ciTvf6Z2GArUOCHHQ3
disqualified
disqualified
disqualified
```

My method:

- parses each url into an array of components,
- accesses the "query" element,
- converts the string of key-value pairs to an associative array,
- checks for the existence of "v" as a key,
- if no "v", access/output the "list" value,
- if "v", output "disqualified"

Comment: There's a link right to the regex code I had. I'm looking for a regex solution.

Comment: @johnh10 I know, this isn't a mistake.  Many (MANY) times OPs on SO ask for regex when it is not essential to use regex for their project.  You will find that frequently non-regex answers are provided because regex is categorically slower than non-regex functional methods.  If you want regex, there is certainly nothing wrong with trincot's answer.

Comment: @johnh10 After a quick test (without knowing your php version and actual volume of data processing) and both of our answers are equally fast. I supposed I'd argue that my code would be easier to read/update.